# Is it possible to call entity_view inside a view mode of the same entity?

Tags: drupal-7

I'm trying to render a view mode which calls entity_view, both with the same entity. The view mode is different from the view mode called in the entity view function.

I know that a view mode calls entity_view, so it's like calling entity_view inside entity_view (nested), with the same entity, but 2 different view modes. I tried but it doesn't work.

What I want is to know if it's possible, maybe it's something that I'm not doing right. If i'ts impossible I want to know why please :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean for example render a commerce_product entity, showing other commerce_product entities of the same type, it is possible indeed.

Check the API you use, you will certainly find a function that make a big part of the job.

Comment: Thanks, but it´s not exactly what I tried to ask. I was talking about rendering product display full ID 1 and inside that display render product display teaser ID 1. Right now I solved my problem differently, but i'm still curious if it's possible.